# Custom carousel size in Bootstrap but responsive

Tags: html, css

Is this carousel style possible for Bootstrap?
I've been trying this for days, I need help :(

> **First picture** is the *wireframe*, ...
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzEl7.png]
>
> and the **second picture** is the *actual look in the browser* I'm working on...
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovVkZ.jpg]

...but it seems like it's not responsive when moved into **larger** screens

Here's the ***HTML***-code:

```
<section id="wow_h>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-style " data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="/assets/Untitled-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="/assets/Untitled-2.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="/assets/Untitled-3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id ="hero-title" class="">
        <h1>Headline 
        </br>
        goes here</h1>
        <p>Hero subtitle goes here
        </br>
        lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And here's the ***CSS***-code:

```
// HOME 
.carousel{
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: -5% 0 0 0;
}
#carouselExampleIndicators{

  img{
      background: cover;
  }
}   

.carousel-indicators > li {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  display: block;
}


#wow_home{
  position: relative;

  #hero-title{
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #f2efef;
      color: #000;
      z-index: 1080;
      padding: 5%;
      margin: 0 0 0 60%;
      position: absolute;

      h1{
          text-transform: none;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code and what you've tried so far. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: we need to see your code to understand what is wrong there... also do you have any error message?

Comment: @D.Schaller , edited my post! Thanks for the corrections

Comment: You're welcome. We like Stackoverflow minimalistic and solution-focused. A clean written question may bring up clean written answers, which makes it easier for all users or guests on SO to enjoy learning and problem-solving.